# How to create GeoJSON constructor in openlayers 3?

Tags: postgis, openlayers, geojson

I wan't to add several GeoJSON-overlay layers from a Postgis-database to an Openlayers 3 map. 
I want to define the source as well as the style, the layer is rendered in ol 3. 
Actually I'm using a slightly modified php-script from Bryan McBride [PHP PostGIS to GeoJSON](https://gist.github.com/bmcbride/1913855/), that uses a GET-call to pass the options of the different layers to the script to define the source of my layer.

```
n2k_do_l = new ol.layer.Vector({
          title: 'Title of Layer',
          visible: false,
          style: new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({color:'rgba(100,250,0,0.1)'}),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'magenta',
                        width: 2
                    })
              }),
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
              attributions: [new ol.Attribution ({html: '<br />Attribution of Layer' })],
              strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
          loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
          var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, projection.getCode(), ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326').getCode());
          $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "./mapdata/get_geojson.php?"+
              "geotable=n2k_do" +
              "&fields=gid as id,sitecode,sitename" +
              "&bbox=" + extent.join(','),
              context: this
              }).done (function (data) {
                 var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                 this.addFeatures (format.readFeatures(data,{
                 dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                 featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                 }));
          });
          }
             })

});
```

For one layer this is ok, but, I would like to use the code from above, to write an extended ol.layer.Vector class (myol3Vector(options)) to create several layers by passing a list of options:

```
n2k_bd_l = new myol3Vector({
            title: "Natura 2000 Birds Directive",
            attribution: "Attribution text",
            geotable: "n2k_bd",
            fields: "gid as id,sitecode,sitename,surfha",
            where: ""
});

n2k_hd_l = new myol3Vector({
            title: "Natura 2000 Habitats Directive",
            attribution: "Other Attribution text",
            geotable: "n2k_hd",
            fields: "gid as id,sitecode,sitename,surfha",
            where: "sitename ilike '%moselle%'" 
});
```

How can I transform my working code to a constructor, that creates multiple layers just by passing a list of options?

Maybe someone can get me a hint, how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Until now I use the following code, which works already:
But maybe there is a better way to implement it??

```
function myol3Vector(options){

var options = options || {};

vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
              title: options.title,
              visible: false,
              style: new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color:'rgba(100,250,0,0.1)'}),
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: 'magenta',
                            width: 2
                            })
                        }),
              source: new ol.source.Vector({
                  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                  attributions: [new ol.Attribution ({html: options.attribution })],
                  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
                  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
                  var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, projection.getCode(), ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326').getCode());
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "./mapdata/get_geojson.php?"+
                      "geotable=" + options.geotable +
                      "&fields=" + options.fields +
                      "&where=" + options.where +
                      "&bbox=" + extent.join(','),
                      context: this
                      }).done (function (data) {
                         var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                         this.addFeatures (format.readFeatures(data,{
                         dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                         featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                         }));
                  });
                  }
                  })

    })

    return vectorLayer;

    };
    ol.inherits(ol3Vector, ol.layer.Vector);
```

Comment: could you rewrite it for https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-vector-layer.html ?